# Facing ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress due to data file issue

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g

I am facing the following error in my database

```
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
```

I mistakenly deleted the wrong newly created datafile, now when I want to start the database it show following errors

```
ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 30 - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 30: '/opt/oracle/PROD/db/apps_st/data/a_txn_ind09.dbf'
```

How can i start my database now?

Comment: You use oracle, so you have an oracle support you pay for no?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in production recover your data file from the last backup. Otherwise try some utility to recover the deleted file in your OS. If none is possible recreate your DB from scratch.